# byte[] to string return null Android

Tags: java, android, null, byte, tostring

i spend a lot of time  to  search how resolve my problem but stil unsuccessful, so i hop some one could help me.

I make my app with android studio: 
i finish my page with login and httm request (100% working to conect and creat new account) and now i trying to make Get request to my server and get username rerver turn my array of bytes that i try to cast on string and in obtain just  null  "".

there is my code:
mainActivity.java

```
  Button b = (Button)findViewById(R.id.b2);
    b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            SyncHttpClient client = new SyncHttpClient();
            RequestParams params = new RequestParams();

            params.put("email", "test3@t.com");

            // Handle request
            client.get("https://......../user/get/", params, new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] response) {
                    // called when response HTTP status is "200 OK"
                    System.out.println("response ----" + response);
                    String res = new String(response); //convetion Byte[] to String that i use
                    Context context = getApplicationContext();
                    Toast.makeText(context, res, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    System.out.println("res ----" + res);

                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] errorResponse, Throwable e) {
                    // called when response HTTP status is "4XX" (eg. 401, 403, 404)
                    System.out.println("errorResponse -----"+errorResponse);
                    String res = new String(errorResponse);
                    Context context = getApplicationContext();
                   // Toast.makeText(context, res, ast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    System.out.println("ERROR--" + res);
                }
            });
        }});
```

Server side it's look like this :
views.py

```
def get_users(req):
"""
Use url :
    https://...../user/get/
With arguments : 
    ?email=EMAIL
"""
email = req.GET.get('email')
if email is not None:
    exists = User.objects.filter(email=email)
    if len(exists) == 0:
        return HttpResponse("Error invalid email !")
    else:
        res = "%s:%s" %(exists[0].username, exists[0].points)
        return HttpResponse(exists[0].username)
else:
    return HttpResponse("Missing information !")
```

And that what i obtain on Android Monitor:

```
I/System.out: response------[B@4136b800
I/System.out: res --------
```

ass you can  see after covertion i have just NULL .
Can Someone help me plz

Comment: You don't have null, you have an empty (or blank) String.

Comment: Try printing the byte array as well (`Arrays.toString(response)`)

Comment: hi  thx for  your help :) 
I have juste try it  like  you said  : 
`System.out.println("response-------" + Arrays.toString(response));`
and on obtain this  on monitoring  :
`I/System.out: response-------[]`

Comment: Looks like your API call returns an empty response.

Comment: Ehhh what does it mean... if i understand in the code there is  no problem ? and  comunication betwen server and client is  good  too ?